# Under what conditions can Assembly.GetName().Name be null?

Tags: c#, .net

This is defined as nullable (`string?`):

```cs
typeof(Foo).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.GetName().Name
```

The docs say:

> Gets or sets the simple name of the assembly. This is usually, but not necessarily, the file name of the manifest file of the assembly, minus its extension.

Under what conditions can the value be null?

Comment: I don't think it can be null, it's probably just that no-one has gotten round to changing it to non-nullable. ECMA-335 Section II.22.2 specifies "*Name* shall index a non-empty string in the String heap" https://www.ecma-international.org/wp-content/uploads/ECMA-335_6th_edition_june_2012.pdf

Comment: Maybe runtime generated code or dynamic assemblies?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An assembly cannot have a null name. This is clearly specified in [ECMA-335](https://www.ecma-international.org/wp-content/uploads/ECMA-335_6th_edition_june_2012.pdf), which defines .NET and the CLI:

> **Section II.22.2**
> ...
> *Name* shall index a non-empty string in the String heap [ERROR]

It's probably just that no-one has gotten round to changing it to non-nullable. You can create your own pull-request on Github to change it to not-null, or raise a bug report if you like.